# safari doesn't update css for dynamic attributes

Tags: css, safari

Here is a simple demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/fE8ry/

I am trying to change the attribute of a div .
and based on the attribute value I have the css . On the page load , the attribute selector works properly and applies appropriate css . but if the attribute is changed via javascript it doesn't apply  the css . 
Happens even on mobile devices.

Works in chrome : v 21.0

safari tested with :  v 5.1.7

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug for jQuery(document).ready() in Safari so the code isn't executed as expected.
You can try this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ele1').attr('data-attr1',false);
        $('#ele1 span').css('display', 'inline');
    });
```

Comment: document.ready has no bug.. atleast not in this case.. don't just randomly shoot anything.. .. you can check the attribute being updated.

Comment: your code is just working because it sets the display property and safari reassigns css